# Ember.js showMore showLess instead of pagination?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, pagination

The title says it all, 
I am after a showMore Button instead of pagination, And because I am new to Ember.js, I've done some research to see if there any examples to assist me with my quest, but with no luck so far, All the examples i stumbled upon, were for pagination.

Any ideas/examples to show how i might achieve that ?
Thanks in advance.

P.S:

If anyone would give a negative vote, Feel Free, But, Please explain why, So that I won't fall in the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out discourse, http://try.discourse.org/

They are open source, https://github.com/discourse/discourse

Comment: Thank you, Your answer is really Helpful! 

Especially in : https://meta.discourse.org/latest/more

when i scroll, it 'Loads more topic ...', This is what i am after, but i will work on converting it from Automatic, to a button action, (Show more button) .